# C# Simulate Key Press

Tags: c#, sendkeys, bsod

I was looking for a way to simulate pressing the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in C#, it must be the right one. I know this can be done for the left one but I couldn't find anything on the right one. It is so I can simulate the key press for the manually triggered bsod.

Thanks

Comment: `...manually triggered bsod.` Wait...what?

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Force-a-Blue-Screen-in-Windows

Comment: I don't know if that's awesome, stupid or just a left-over debug key (most likely the last one)...anyway, nice to know, thanks.

Comment: I'm going to enable this on my co-worker's PC and use AutoHotKey to emulate the key-presses when he types his name. Muahahahahahaha.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [keybd_event](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.keybd_event) event to simulate right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key press.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo); 

public const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001; //Key down flag
public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002; //Key up flag
public const int VK_RCONTROL = 0xA3; //Right Control key code
```

Usage:

```
keybd_event(VK_RCONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
keybd_event(VK_RCONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

For other key simulation [here is virtual key codes list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You might have some luck with the Windows Input Simulator http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are usign AutoHotKey try looking [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm). with `{RControl}` you should get what you want

Update: For .NET try looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more info, but AFAIK you can't send right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. guess you must use win32 to accomplish it

Comment: Thanks for the link but I was looking to do it from a vs app with C#, is this possible? If not I will look at the AutoHotKey, thanks.