# Programmatically execute Ctrl-H

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Simulate Key Press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307868/c-sharp-simulate-key-press)

I need a way in C# to "type" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in code when a user clicks a button.  I am working on a Word addin that customizes the ribbon.  When a user clicks my "Replace" button, I want the Replace dialog to show.  I can't figure out how to get to that dialog box, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> brings it up.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100285/how-to-detect-the-currently-pressed-key) at handling different key combinations. Are you using VSTO?

EDIT: Just reread and understand you're looking at typing those keys! I'll adjust accordingly!

EDIT: The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307868/c-sharp-simulate-key-press) covers simulating key presses.