# Simulate keyboard input in C#

Tags: c#, input, keyboard, simulation

I need to know how to simulate keyboard input for keys `W`, `S`, `A`, `D`.

I've used `SendKeys` with no avail as well as the `InputSimulator` library with no fix.

What I'm trying to do is make it to where applications such as games (Battlefield, Natural Selection, ect. Newer FPS games) will register these simulated keys as real keystrokes. I'm trying to make a virtual controller program where external controls will register as keyboard inputs for these games.

Is there a way to manually simulate keyboard input like there is with something like this?

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", 
           CharSet = CharSet.Auto, 
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, 
                                      uint dx, 
                                      uint dy, 
                                      int cButtons, 
                                      uint dwExtraInfo);
```

Comment: Show the send keys syntax you used

Comment: Why on Earth would you simulate keyboard input with a *mouse_event*?

Comment: I'm not wanting to use a mouse_event I'm speaking of something like that that sends a message to the computer to simulate that button being pressed. And the keys syntax I used was just 
Sendkeys.sendwait("W"); which didn't work inside of games.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I like @Gareth's approach at it. However, in his method, you need to hard code your key strokes into the SendInputWithAPI() method. I made a few changes to the code; you now can call Send() and pass ScanCodeShort parameter to it. This allows you to pass any keystroke to it, any time, any place.

```
 public class Keyboard
{
    public void Send(ScanCodeShort a)
    {
        INPUT[] Inputs = new INPUT[1];
        INPUT Input = new INPUT();
        Input.type = 1; // 1 = Keyboard Input
        Input.U.ki.wScan = a;
        Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.SCANCODE;
        Inputs[0] = Input;
        SendInput(1, Inputs, INPUT.Size);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Declaration of external SendInput method
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern uint SendInput(
        uint nInputs,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In] INPUT[] pInputs,
        int cbSize);


    // Declare the INPUT struct
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct INPUT
    {
        public uint type;
        public InputUnion U;
        public static int Size
        {
            get { return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)); }
        }
    }

    // Declare the InputUnion struct
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct InputUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal MOUSEINPUT mi;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal KEYBDINPUT ki;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal HARDWAREINPUT hi;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        internal int dx;
        internal int dy;
        internal MouseEventDataXButtons mouseData;
        internal MOUSEEVENTF dwFlags;
        internal uint time;
        internal UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum MouseEventDataXButtons : uint
    {
        Nothing = 0x00000000,
        XBUTTON1 = 0x00000001,
        XBUTTON2 = 0x00000002
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum MOUSEEVENTF : uint
    {
        ABSOLUTE = 0x8000,
        HWHEEL = 0x01000,
        MOVE = 0x0001,
        MOVE_NOCOALESCE = 0x2000,
        LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,
        LEFTUP = 0x0004,
        RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,
        RIGHTUP = 0x0010,
        MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,
        MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,
        VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000,
        WHEEL = 0x0800,
        XDOWN = 0x0080,
        XUP = 0x0100
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        internal VirtualKeyShort wVk;
        internal ScanCodeShort wScan;
        internal KEYEVENTF dwFlags;
        internal int time;
        internal UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum KEYEVENTF : uint
    {
        EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001,
        KEYUP = 0x0002,
        SCANCODE = 0x0008,
        UNICODE = 0x0004
    }

    public enum VirtualKeyShort : short
    {
        ///<summary>
        ///Left mouse button
        ///</summary>
        LBUTTON = 0x01,
        ///<summary>
        ///Right mouse button
        ///</summary>
        RBUTTON = 0x02,
        ///<summary>
        ///Control-break processing
        ///</summary>
        CANCEL = 0x03,
        ///<summary>
        ///Middle mouse button (three-button mouse)
        ///</summary>
        MBUTTON = 0x04,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: X1 mouse button
        ///</summary>
        XBUTTON1 = 0x05,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: X2 mouse button
        ///</summary>
        XBUTTON2 = 0x06,
        ///<summary>
        ///BACKSPACE key
        ///</summary>
        BACK = 0x08,
        ///<summary>
        ///TAB key
        ///</summary>
        TAB = 0x09,
        ///<summary>
        ///CLEAR key
        ///</summary>
        CLEAR = 0x0C,
        ///<summary>
        ///ENTER key
        ///</summary>
        RETURN = 0x0D,
        ///<summary>
        ///SHIFT key
        ///</summary>
        SHIFT = 0x10,
        ///<summary>
        ///CTRL key
        ///</summary>
        CONTROL = 0x11,
        ///<summary>
        ///ALT key
        ///</summary>
        MENU = 0x12,
        ///<summary>
        ///PAUSE key
        ///</summary>
        PAUSE = 0x13,
        ///<summary>
        ///CAPS LOCK key
        ///</summary>
        CAPITAL = 0x14,
        ///<summary>
        ///Input Method Editor (IME) Kana mode
        ///</summary>
        KANA = 0x15,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME Hangul mode
        ///</summary>
        HANGUL = 0x15,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME Junja mode
        ///</summary>
        JUNJA = 0x17,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME final mode
        ///</summary>
        FINAL = 0x18,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME Hanja mode
        ///</summary>
        HANJA = 0x19,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME Kanji mode
        ///</summary>
        KANJI = 0x19,
        ///<summary>
        ///ESC key
        ///</summary>
        ESCAPE = 0x1B,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME convert
        ///</summary>
        CONVERT = 0x1C,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME nonconvert
        ///</summary>
        NONCONVERT = 0x1D,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME accept
        ///</summary>
        ACCEPT = 0x1E,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME mode change request
        ///</summary>
        MODECHANGE = 0x1F,
        ///<summary>
        ///SPACEBAR
        ///</summary>
        SPACE = 0x20,
        ///<summary>
        ///PAGE UP key
        ///</summary>
        PRIOR = 0x21,
        ///<summary>
        ///PAGE DOWN key
        ///</summary>
        NEXT = 0x22,
        ///<summary>
        ///END key
        ///</summary>
        END = 0x23,
        ///<summary>
        ///HOME key
        ///</summary>
        HOME = 0x24,
        ///<summary>
        ///LEFT ARROW key
        ///</summary>
        LEFT = 0x25,
        ///<summary>
        ///UP ARROW key
        ///</summary>
        UP = 0x26,
        ///<summary>
        ///RIGHT ARROW key
        ///</summary>
        RIGHT = 0x27,
        ///<summary>
        ///DOWN ARROW key
        ///</summary>
        DOWN = 0x28,
        ///<summary>
        ///SELECT key
        ///</summary>
        SELECT = 0x29,
        ///<summary>
        ///PRINT key
        ///</summary>
        PRINT = 0x2A,
        ///<summary>
        ///EXECUTE key
        ///</summary>
        EXECUTE = 0x2B,
        ///<summary>
        ///PRINT SCREEN key
        ///</summary>
        SNAPSHOT = 0x2C,
        ///<summary>
        ///INS key
        ///</summary>
        INSERT = 0x2D,
        ///<summary>
        ///DEL key
        ///</summary>
        DELETE = 0x2E,
        ///<summary>
        ///HELP key
        ///</summary>
        HELP = 0x2F,
        ///<summary>
        ///0 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_0 = 0x30,
        ///<summary>
        ///1 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_1 = 0x31,
        ///<summary>
        ///2 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_2 = 0x32,
        ///<summary>
        ///3 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_3 = 0x33,
        ///<summary>
        ///4 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_4 = 0x34,
        ///<summary>
        ///5 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_5 = 0x35,
        ///<summary>
        ///6 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_6 = 0x36,
        ///<summary>
        ///7 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_7 = 0x37,
        ///<summary>
        ///8 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_8 = 0x38,
        ///<summary>
        ///9 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_9 = 0x39,
        ///<summary>
        ///A key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_A = 0x41,
        ///<summary>
        ///B key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_B = 0x42,
        ///<summary>
        ///C key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_C = 0x43,
        ///<summary>
        ///D key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_D = 0x44,
        ///<summary>
        ///E key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_E = 0x45,
        ///<summary>
        ///F key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_F = 0x46,
        ///<summary>
        ///G key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_G = 0x47,
        ///<summary>
        ///H key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_H = 0x48,
        ///<summary>
        ///I key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_I = 0x49,
        ///<summary>
        ///J key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_J = 0x4A,
        ///<summary>
        ///K key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_K = 0x4B,
        ///<summary>
        ///L key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_L = 0x4C,
        ///<summary>
        ///M key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_M = 0x4D,
        ///<summary>
        ///N key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_N = 0x4E,
        ///<summary>
        ///O key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_O = 0x4F,
        ///<summary>
        ///P key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_P = 0x50,
        ///<summary>
        ///Q key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_Q = 0x51,
        ///<summary>
        ///R key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_R = 0x52,
        ///<summary>
        ///S key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_S = 0x53,
        ///<summary>
        ///T key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_T = 0x54,
        ///<summary>
        ///U key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_U = 0x55,
        ///<summary>
        ///V key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_V = 0x56,
        ///<summary>
        ///W key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_W = 0x57,
        ///<summary>
        ///X key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_X = 0x58,
        ///<summary>
        ///Y key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_Y = 0x59,
        ///<summary>
        ///Z key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_Z = 0x5A,
        ///<summary>
        ///Left Windows key (Microsoft Natural keyboard) 
        ///</summary>
        LWIN = 0x5B,
        ///<summary>
        ///Right Windows key (Natural keyboard)
        ///</summary>
        RWIN = 0x5C,
        ///<summary>
        ///Applications key (Natural keyboard)
        ///</summary>
        APPS = 0x5D,
        ///<summary>
        ///Computer Sleep key
        ///</summary>
        SLEEP = 0x5F,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 0 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD0 = 0x60,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 1 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD1 = 0x61,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 2 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD2 = 0x62,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 3 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD3 = 0x63,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 4 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD4 = 0x64,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 5 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD5 = 0x65,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 6 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD6 = 0x66,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 7 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD7 = 0x67,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 8 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD8 = 0x68,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 9 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD9 = 0x69,
        ///<summary>
        ///Multiply key
        ///</summary>
        MULTIPLY = 0x6A,
        ///<summary>
        ///Add key
        ///</summary>
        ADD = 0x6B,
        ///<summary>
        ///Separator key
        ///</summary>
        SEPARATOR = 0x6C,
        ///<summary>
        ///Subtract key
        ///</summary>
        SUBTRACT = 0x6D,
        ///<summary>
        ///Decimal key
        ///</summary>
        DECIMAL = 0x6E,
        ///<summary>
        ///Divide key
        ///</summary>
        DIVIDE = 0x6F,
        ///<summary>
        ///F1 key
        ///</summary>
        F1 = 0x70,
        ///<summary>
        ///F2 key
        ///</summary>
        F2 = 0x71,
        ///<summary>
        ///F3 key
        ///</summary>
        F3 = 0x72,
        ///<summary>
        ///F4 key
        ///</summary>
        F4 = 0x73,
        ///<summary>
        ///F5 key
        ///</summary>
        F5 = 0x74,
        ///<summary>
        ///F6 key
        ///</summary>
        F6 = 0x75,
        ///<summary>
        ///F7 key
        ///</summary>
        F7 = 0x76,
        ///<summary>
        ///F8 key
        ///</summary>
        F8 = 0x77,
        ///<summary>
        ///F9 key
        ///</summary>
        F9 = 0x78,
        ///<summary>
        ///F10 key
        ///</summary>
        F10 = 0x79,
        ///<summary>
        ///F11 key
        ///</summary>
        F11 = 0x7A,
        ///<summary>
        ///F12 key
        ///</summary>
        F12 = 0x7B,
        ///<summary>
        ///F13 key
        ///</summary>
        F13 = 0x7C,
        ///<summary>
        ///F14 key
        ///</summary>
        F14 = 0x7D,
        ///<summary>
        ///F15 key
        ///</summary>
        F15 = 0x7E,
        ///<summary>
        ///F16 key
        ///</summary>
        F16 = 0x7F,
        ///<summary>
        ///F17 key  
        ///</summary>
        F17 = 0x80,
        ///<summary>
        ///F18 key  
        ///</summary>
        F18 = 0x81,
        ///<summary>
        ///F19 key  
        ///</summary>
        F19 = 0x82,
        ///<summary>
        ///F20 key  
        ///</summary>
        F20 = 0x83,
        ///<summary>
        ///F21 key  
        ///</summary>
        F21 = 0x84,
        ///<summary>
        ///F22 key, (PPC only) Key used to lock device.
        ///</summary>
        F22 = 0x85,
        ///<summary>
        ///F23 key  
        ///</summary>
        F23 = 0x86,
        ///<summary>
        ///F24 key  
        ///</summary>
        F24 = 0x87,
        ///<summary>
        ///NUM LOCK key
        ///</summary>
        NUMLOCK = 0x90,
        ///<summary>
        ///SCROLL LOCK key
        ///</summary>
        SCROLL = 0x91,
        ///<summary>
        ///Left SHIFT key
        ///</summary>
        LSHIFT = 0xA0,
        ///<summary>
        ///Right SHIFT key
        ///</summary>
        RSHIFT = 0xA1,
        ///<summary>
        ///Left CONTROL key
        ///</summary>
        LCONTROL = 0xA2,
        ///<summary>
        ///Right CONTROL key
        ///</summary>
        RCONTROL = 0xA3,
        ///<summary>
        ///Left MENU key
        ///</summary>
        LMENU = 0xA4,
        ///<summary>
        ///Right MENU key
        ///</summary>
        RMENU = 0xA5,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Back key
        ///</summary>
        BROWSER_BACK = 0xA6,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Forward key
        ///</summary>
        BROWSER_FORWARD = 0xA7,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Refresh key
        ///</summary>
        BROWSER_REFRESH = 0xA8,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Stop key
        ///</summary>
        BROWSER_STOP = 0xA9,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Search key 
        ///</summary>
        BROWSER_SEARCH = 0xAA,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Favorites key
        ///</summary>
        BROWSER_FAVORITES = 0xAB,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Start and Home key
        ///</summary>
        BROWSER_HOME = 0xAC,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Volume Mute key
        ///</summary>
        VOLUME_MUTE = 0xAD,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Volume Down key
        ///</summary>
        VOLUME_DOWN = 0xAE,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Volume Up key
        ///</summary>
        VOLUME_UP = 0xAF,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Next Track key
        ///</summary>
        MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 0xB0,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Previous Track key
        ///</summary>
        MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 0xB1,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Stop Media key
        ///</summary>
        MEDIA_STOP = 0xB2,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Play/Pause Media key
        ///</summary>
        MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0xB3,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Start Mail key
        ///</summary>
        LAUNCH_MAIL = 0xB4,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Select Media key
        ///</summary>
        LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT = 0xB5,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Start Application 1 key
        ///</summary>
        LAUNCH_APP1 = 0xB6,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Start Application 2 key
        ///</summary>
        LAUNCH_APP2 = 0xB7,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
        ///</summary>
        OEM_1 = 0xBA,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the '+' key
        ///</summary>
        OEM_PLUS = 0xBB,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the ',' key
        ///</summary>
        OEM_COMMA = 0xBC,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the '-' key
        ///</summary>
        OEM_MINUS = 0xBD,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the '.' key
        ///</summary>
        OEM_PERIOD = 0xBE,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
        ///</summary>
        OEM_2 = 0xBF,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard. 
        ///</summary>
        OEM_3 = 0xC0,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard. 
        ///</summary>
        OEM_4 = 0xDB,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard. 
        ///</summary>
        OEM_5 = 0xDC,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard. 
        ///</summary>
        OEM_6 = 0xDD,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard. 
        ///</summary>
        OEM_7 = 0xDE,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
        ///</summary>
        OEM_8 = 0xDF,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Either the angle bracket key or the backslash key on the RT 102-key keyboard
        ///</summary>
        OEM_102 = 0xE2,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 95/98/Me, Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000/XP: IME PROCESS key
        ///</summary>
        PROCESSKEY = 0xE5,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Used to pass Unicode characters as if they were keystrokes.
        ///The VK_PACKET key is the low word of a 32-bit Virtual Key value used for non-keyboard input methods. For more information,
        ///see Remark in KEYBDINPUT, SendInput, WM_KEYDOWN, and WM_KEYUP
        ///</summary>
        PACKET = 0xE7,
        ///<summary>
        ///Attn key
        ///</summary>
        ATTN = 0xF6,
        ///<summary>
        ///CrSel key
        ///</summary>
        CRSEL = 0xF7,
        ///<summary>
        ///ExSel key
        ///</summary>
        EXSEL = 0xF8,
        ///<summary>
        ///Erase EOF key
        ///</summary>
        EREOF = 0xF9,
        ///<summary>
        ///Play key
        ///</summary>
        PLAY = 0xFA,
        ///<summary>
        ///Zoom key
        ///</summary>
        ZOOM = 0xFB,
        ///<summary>
        ///Reserved 
        ///</summary>
        NONAME = 0xFC,
        ///<summary>
        ///PA1 key
        ///</summary>
        PA1 = 0xFD,
        ///<summary>
        ///Clear key
        ///</summary>
        OEM_CLEAR = 0xFE
    }

    public enum ScanCodeShort : short
    {
        LBUTTON = 0,
        RBUTTON = 0,
        CANCEL = 70,
        MBUTTON = 0,
        XBUTTON1 = 0,
        XBUTTON2 = 0,
        BACK = 14,
        TAB = 15,
        CLEAR = 76,
        RETURN = 28,
        SHIFT = 42,
        CONTROL = 29,
        MENU = 56,
        PAUSE = 0,
        CAPITAL = 58,
        KANA = 0,
        HANGUL = 0,
        JUNJA = 0,
        FINAL = 0,
        HANJA = 0,
        KANJI = 0,
        ESCAPE = 1,
        CONVERT = 0,
        NONCONVERT = 0,
        ACCEPT = 0,
        MODECHANGE = 0,
        SPACE = 57,
        PRIOR = 73,
        NEXT = 81,
        END = 79,
        HOME = 71,
        LEFT = 75,
        UP = 72,
        RIGHT = 77,
        DOWN = 80,
        SELECT = 0,
        PRINT = 0,
        EXECUTE = 0,
        SNAPSHOT = 84,
        INSERT = 82,
        DELETE = 83,
        HELP = 99,
        KEY_0 = 11,
        KEY_1 = 2,
        KEY_2 = 3,
        KEY_3 = 4,
        KEY_4 = 5,
        KEY_5 = 6,
        KEY_6 = 7,
        KEY_7 = 8,
        KEY_8 = 9,
        KEY_9 = 10,
        KEY_A = 30,
        KEY_B = 48,
        KEY_C = 46,
        KEY_D = 32,
        KEY_E = 18,
        KEY_F = 33,
        KEY_G = 34,
        KEY_H = 35,
        KEY_I = 23,
        KEY_J = 36,
        KEY_K = 37,
        KEY_L = 38,
        KEY_M = 50,
        KEY_N = 49,
        KEY_O = 24,
        KEY_P = 25,
        KEY_Q = 16,
        KEY_R = 19,
        KEY_S = 31,
        KEY_T = 20,
        KEY_U = 22,
        KEY_V = 47,
        KEY_W = 17,
        KEY_X = 45,
        KEY_Y = 21,
        KEY_Z = 44,
        LWIN = 91,
        RWIN = 92,
        APPS = 93,
        SLEEP = 95,
        NUMPAD0 = 82,
        NUMPAD1 = 79,
        NUMPAD2 = 80,
        NUMPAD3 = 81,
        NUMPAD4 = 75,
        NUMPAD5 = 76,
        NUMPAD6 = 77,
        NUMPAD7 = 71,
        NUMPAD8 = 72,
        NUMPAD9 = 73,
        MULTIPLY = 55,
        ADD = 78,
        SEPARATOR = 0,
        SUBTRACT = 74,
        DECIMAL = 83,
        DIVIDE = 53,
        F1 = 59,
        F2 = 60,
        F3 = 61,
        F4 = 62,
        F5 = 63,
        F6 = 64,
        F7 = 65,
        F8 = 66,
        F9 = 67,
        F10 = 68,
        F11 = 87,
        F12 = 88,
        F13 = 100,
        F14 = 101,
        F15 = 102,
        F16 = 103,
        F17 = 104,
        F18 = 105,
        F19 = 106,
        F20 = 107,
        F21 = 108,
        F22 = 109,
        F23 = 110,
        F24 = 118,
        NUMLOCK = 69,
        SCROLL = 70,
        LSHIFT = 42,
        RSHIFT = 54,
        LCONTROL = 29,
        RCONTROL = 29,
        LMENU = 56,
        RMENU = 56,
        BROWSER_BACK = 106,
        BROWSER_FORWARD = 105,
        BROWSER_REFRESH = 103,
        BROWSER_STOP = 104,
        BROWSER_SEARCH = 101,
        BROWSER_FAVORITES = 102,
        BROWSER_HOME = 50,
        VOLUME_MUTE = 32,
        VOLUME_DOWN = 46,
        VOLUME_UP = 48,
        MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 25,
        MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 16,
        MEDIA_STOP = 36,
        MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 34,
        LAUNCH_MAIL = 108,
        LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT = 109,
        LAUNCH_APP1 = 107,
        LAUNCH_APP2 = 33,
        OEM_1 = 39,
        OEM_PLUS = 13,
        OEM_COMMA = 51,
        OEM_MINUS = 12,
        OEM_PERIOD = 52,
        OEM_2 = 53,
        OEM_3 = 41,
        OEM_4 = 26,
        OEM_5 = 43,
        OEM_6 = 27,
        OEM_7 = 40,
        OEM_8 = 0,
        OEM_102 = 86,
        PROCESSKEY = 0,
        PACKET = 0,
        ATTN = 0,
        CRSEL = 0,
        EXSEL = 0,
        EREOF = 93,
        PLAY = 0,
        ZOOM = 98,
        NONAME = 0,
        PA1 = 0,
        OEM_CLEAR = 0,
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Define HARDWAREINPUT struct
    /// </summary>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        internal int uMsg;
        internal short wParamL;
        internal short wParamH;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to run the script as Administrator if your game runs as administrator. Otherwise the game won't pick up the input. - Cost me 2 hours to find out.

Comment: FYI, to avoid the massive virtual key/scan code enums, just use MapVirtualKeyA (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeya), that way you can use the Keys enum from the WinForms library (cast to a uint) and it will return the appropriate scan code.

Comment: This one really messed up input on my PC somehow, locking my Shift key no matter what I did to try to fix it and forcing me to reboot.

Comment: This implementation has a bug that holds the key forever, instead of just once. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how to use it?

Answer (score 30):

Have you tried using `SendInput` which supersedes `keybd_event`?

To call SendInput from C#, you're going to need to create a whole bunch of structs. Fortunately, most of this information can be gleaned from [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net).

Looking at the pinvoke documentation for [SendInput](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/INPUT.html) and the [INPUT](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendInput) struct, I came up with the following. The method I've written at the top called *SendInputWithAPI* is calling SendInput to simulate the sending of "wsad". The rest of the code is just the structure declarations you need to make it work.

```
    void SendInputWithAPI()
    {
        INPUT[] Inputs = new INPUT[4];
        INPUT Input = new INPUT();

        Input.type = 1; // 1 = Keyboard Input
        Input.U.ki.wScan = ScanCodeShort.KEY_W;
        Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.SCANCODE;   
        Inputs[0] = Input;

        Input.type = 1; // 1 = Keyboard Input
        Input.U.ki.wScan = ScanCodeShort.KEY_S;
        Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.SCANCODE;
        Inputs[1] = Input;

        Input.type = 1; // 1 = Keyboard Input
        Input.U.ki.wScan = ScanCodeShort.KEY_A;
        Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.SCANCODE;
        Inputs[2] = Input;

        Input.type = 1; // 1 = Keyboard Input
        Input.U.ki.wScan = ScanCodeShort.KEY_D;
        Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.SCANCODE;
        Inputs[3] = Input;


        SendInput(4, Inputs, INPUT.Size);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Declaration of external SendInput method
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern uint SendInput(
        uint nInputs,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In] INPUT[] pInputs,
        int cbSize);


    // Declare the INPUT struct
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct INPUT
    {
        internal uint type;
        internal InputUnion U;
        internal static int Size
        {
            get { return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)); }
        }
    }

    // Declare the InputUnion struct
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal struct InputUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal MOUSEINPUT mi;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal KEYBDINPUT ki;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal HARDWAREINPUT hi;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        internal int dx;
        internal int dy;
        internal MouseEventDataXButtons mouseData;
        internal MOUSEEVENTF dwFlags;
        internal uint time;
        internal UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [Flags]
    internal enum MouseEventDataXButtons : uint
    {
        Nothing = 0x00000000,
        XBUTTON1 = 0x00000001,
        XBUTTON2 = 0x00000002
    }

    [Flags]
    internal enum MOUSEEVENTF : uint
    {
        ABSOLUTE = 0x8000,
        HWHEEL = 0x01000,
        MOVE = 0x0001,
        MOVE_NOCOALESCE = 0x2000,
        LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,
        LEFTUP = 0x0004,
        RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,
        RIGHTUP = 0x0010,
        MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,
        MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,
        VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000,
        WHEEL = 0x0800,
        XDOWN = 0x0080,
        XUP = 0x0100
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        internal VirtualKeyShort wVk;
        internal ScanCodeShort wScan;
        internal KEYEVENTF dwFlags;
        internal int time;
        internal UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [Flags]
    internal enum KEYEVENTF : uint
    {
        EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001,
        KEYUP = 0x0002,
        SCANCODE = 0x0008,
        UNICODE = 0x0004
    }

    internal enum VirtualKeyShort : short
    {
        ///<summary>
        ///Left mouse button
        ///</summary>
        LBUTTON = 0x01,
        ///<summary>
        ///Right mouse button
        ///</summary>
        RBUTTON = 0x02,
        ///<summary>
        ///Control-break processing
        ///</summary>
        CANCEL = 0x03,
        ///<summary>
        ///Middle mouse button (three-button mouse)
        ///</summary>
        MBUTTON = 0x04,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: X1 mouse button
        ///</summary>
        XBUTTON1 = 0x05,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: X2 mouse button
        ///</summary>
        XBUTTON2 = 0x06,
        ///<summary>
        ///BACKSPACE key
        ///</summary>
        BACK = 0x08,
        ///<summary>
        ///TAB key
        ///</summary>
        TAB = 0x09,
        ///<summary>
        ///CLEAR key
        ///</summary>
        CLEAR = 0x0C,
        ///<summary>
        ///ENTER key
        ///</summary>
        RETURN = 0x0D,
        ///<summary>
        ///SHIFT key
        ///</summary>
        SHIFT = 0x10,
        ///<summary>
        ///CTRL key
        ///</summary>
        CONTROL = 0x11,
        ///<summary>
        ///ALT key
        ///</summary>
        MENU = 0x12,
        ///<summary>
        ///PAUSE key
        ///</summary>
        PAUSE = 0x13,
        ///<summary>
        ///CAPS LOCK key
        ///</summary>
        CAPITAL = 0x14,
        ///<summary>
        ///Input Method Editor (IME) Kana mode
        ///</summary>
        KANA = 0x15,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME Hangul mode
        ///</summary>
        HANGUL = 0x15,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME Junja mode
        ///</summary>
        JUNJA = 0x17,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME final mode
        ///</summary>
        FINAL = 0x18,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME Hanja mode
        ///</summary>
        HANJA = 0x19,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME Kanji mode
        ///</summary>
        KANJI = 0x19,
        ///<summary>
        ///ESC key
        ///</summary>
        ESCAPE = 0x1B,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME convert
        ///</summary>
        CONVERT = 0x1C,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME nonconvert
        ///</summary>
        NONCONVERT = 0x1D,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME accept
        ///</summary>
        ACCEPT = 0x1E,
        ///<summary>
        ///IME mode change request
        ///</summary>
        MODECHANGE = 0x1F,
        ///<summary>
        ///SPACEBAR
        ///</summary>
        SPACE = 0x20,
        ///<summary>
        ///PAGE UP key
        ///</summary>
        PRIOR = 0x21,
        ///<summary>
        ///PAGE DOWN key
        ///</summary>
        NEXT = 0x22,
        ///<summary>
        ///END key
        ///</summary>
        END = 0x23,
        ///<summary>
        ///HOME key
        ///</summary>
        HOME = 0x24,
        ///<summary>
        ///LEFT ARROW key
        ///</summary>
        LEFT = 0x25,
        ///<summary>
        ///UP ARROW key
        ///</summary>
        UP = 0x26,
        ///<summary>
        ///RIGHT ARROW key
        ///</summary>
        RIGHT = 0x27,
        ///<summary>
        ///DOWN ARROW key
        ///</summary>
        DOWN = 0x28,
        ///<summary>
        ///SELECT key
        ///</summary>
        SELECT = 0x29,
        ///<summary>
        ///PRINT key
        ///</summary>
        PRINT = 0x2A,
        ///<summary>
        ///EXECUTE key
        ///</summary>
        EXECUTE = 0x2B,
        ///<summary>
        ///PRINT SCREEN key
        ///</summary>
        SNAPSHOT = 0x2C,
        ///<summary>
        ///INS key
        ///</summary>
        INSERT = 0x2D,
        ///<summary>
        ///DEL key
        ///</summary>
        DELETE = 0x2E,
        ///<summary>
        ///HELP key
        ///</summary>
        HELP = 0x2F,
        ///<summary>
        ///0 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_0 = 0x30,
        ///<summary>
        ///1 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_1 = 0x31,
        ///<summary>
        ///2 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_2 = 0x32,
        ///<summary>
        ///3 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_3 = 0x33,
        ///<summary>
        ///4 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_4 = 0x34,
        ///<summary>
        ///5 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_5 = 0x35,
        ///<summary>
        ///6 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_6 = 0x36,
        ///<summary>
        ///7 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_7 = 0x37,
        ///<summary>
        ///8 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_8 = 0x38,
        ///<summary>
        ///9 key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_9 = 0x39,
        ///<summary>
        ///A key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_A = 0x41,
        ///<summary>
        ///B key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_B = 0x42,
        ///<summary>
        ///C key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_C = 0x43,
        ///<summary>
        ///D key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_D = 0x44,
        ///<summary>
        ///E key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_E = 0x45,
        ///<summary>
        ///F key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_F = 0x46,
        ///<summary>
        ///G key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_G = 0x47,
        ///<summary>
        ///H key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_H = 0x48,
        ///<summary>
        ///I key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_I = 0x49,
        ///<summary>
        ///J key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_J = 0x4A,
        ///<summary>
        ///K key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_K = 0x4B,
        ///<summary>
        ///L key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_L = 0x4C,
        ///<summary>
        ///M key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_M = 0x4D,
        ///<summary>
        ///N key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_N = 0x4E,
        ///<summary>
        ///O key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_O = 0x4F,
        ///<summary>
        ///P key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_P = 0x50,
        ///<summary>
        ///Q key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_Q = 0x51,
        ///<summary>
        ///R key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_R = 0x52,
        ///<summary>
        ///S key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_S = 0x53,
        ///<summary>
        ///T key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_T = 0x54,
        ///<summary>
        ///U key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_U = 0x55,
        ///<summary>
        ///V key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_V = 0x56,
        ///<summary>
        ///W key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_W = 0x57,
        ///<summary>
        ///X key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_X = 0x58,
        ///<summary>
        ///Y key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_Y = 0x59,
        ///<summary>
        ///Z key
        ///</summary>
        KEY_Z = 0x5A,
        ///<summary>
        ///Left Windows key (Microsoft Natural keyboard) 
        ///</summary>
        LWIN = 0x5B,
        ///<summary>
        ///Right Windows key (Natural keyboard)
        ///</summary>
        RWIN = 0x5C,
        ///<summary>
        ///Applications key (Natural keyboard)
        ///</summary>
        APPS = 0x5D,
        ///<summary>
        ///Computer Sleep key
        ///</summary>
        SLEEP = 0x5F,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 0 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD0 = 0x60,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 1 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD1 = 0x61,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 2 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD2 = 0x62,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 3 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD3 = 0x63,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 4 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD4 = 0x64,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 5 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD5 = 0x65,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 6 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD6 = 0x66,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 7 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD7 = 0x67,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 8 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD8 = 0x68,
        ///<summary>
        ///Numeric keypad 9 key
        ///</summary>
        NUMPAD9 = 0x69,
        ///<summary>
        ///Multiply key
        ///</summary>
        MULTIPLY = 0x6A,
        ///<summary>
        ///Add key
        ///</summary>
        ADD = 0x6B,
        ///<summary>
        ///Separator key
        ///</summary>
        SEPARATOR = 0x6C,
        ///<summary>
        ///Subtract key
        ///</summary>
        SUBTRACT = 0x6D,
        ///<summary>
        ///Decimal key
        ///</summary>
        DECIMAL = 0x6E,
        ///<summary>
        ///Divide key
        ///</summary>
        DIVIDE = 0x6F,
        ///<summary>
        ///F1 key
        ///</summary>
        F1 = 0x70,
        ///<summary>
        ///F2 key
        ///</summary>
        F2 = 0x71,
        ///<summary>
        ///F3 key
        ///</summary>
        F3 = 0x72,
        ///<summary>
        ///F4 key
        ///</summary>
        F4 = 0x73,
        ///<summary>
        ///F5 key
        ///</summary>
        F5 = 0x74,
        ///<summary>
        ///F6 key
        ///</summary>
        F6 = 0x75,
        ///<summary>
        ///F7 key
        ///</summary>
        F7 = 0x76,
        ///<summary>
        ///F8 key
        ///</summary>
        F8 = 0x77,
        ///<summary>
        ///F9 key
        ///</summary>
        F9 = 0x78,
        ///<summary>
        ///F10 key
        ///</summary>
        F10 = 0x79,
        ///<summary>
        ///F11 key
        ///</summary>
        F11 = 0x7A,
        ///<summary>
        ///F12 key
        ///</summary>
        F12 = 0x7B,
        ///<summary>
        ///F13 key
        ///</summary>
        F13 = 0x7C,
        ///<summary>
        ///F14 key
        ///</summary>
        F14 = 0x7D,
        ///<summary>
        ///F15 key
        ///</summary>
        F15 = 0x7E,
        ///<summary>
        ///F16 key
        ///</summary>
        F16 = 0x7F,
        ///<summary>
        ///F17 key  
        ///</summary>
        F17 = 0x80,
        ///<summary>
        ///F18 key  
        ///</summary>
        F18 = 0x81,
        ///<summary>
        ///F19 key  
        ///</summary>
        F19 = 0x82,
        ///<summary>
        ///F20 key  
        ///</summary>
        F20 = 0x83,
        ///<summary>
        ///F21 key  
        ///</summary>
        F21 = 0x84,
        ///<summary>
        ///F22 key, (PPC only) Key used to lock device.
        ///</summary>
        F22 = 0x85,
        ///<summary>
        ///F23 key  
        ///</summary>
        F23 = 0x86,
        ///<summary>
        ///F24 key  
        ///</summary>
        F24 = 0x87,
        ///<summary>
        ///NUM LOCK key
        ///</summary>
        NUMLOCK = 0x90,
        ///<summary>
        ///SCROLL LOCK key
        ///</summary>
        SCROLL = 0x91,
        ///<summary>
        ///Left SHIFT key
        ///</summary>
        LSHIFT = 0xA0,
        ///<summary>
        ///Right SHIFT key
        ///</summary>
        RSHIFT = 0xA1,
        ///<summary>
        ///Left CONTROL key
        ///</summary>
        LCONTROL = 0xA2,
        ///<summary>
        ///Right CONTROL key
        ///</summary>
        RCONTROL = 0xA3,
        ///<summary>
        ///Left MENU key
        ///</summary>
        LMENU = 0xA4,
        ///<summary>
        ///Right MENU key
        ///</summary>
        RMENU = 0xA5,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Back key
        ///</summary>
        BROWSER_BACK = 0xA6,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Forward key
        ///</summary>
        BROWSER_FORWARD = 0xA7,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Refresh key
        ///</summary>
        BROWSER_REFRESH = 0xA8,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Stop key
        ///</summary>
        BROWSER_STOP = 0xA9,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Search key 
        ///</summary>
        BROWSER_SEARCH = 0xAA,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Favorites key
        ///</summary>
        BROWSER_FAVORITES = 0xAB,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Start and Home key
        ///</summary>
        BROWSER_HOME = 0xAC,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Volume Mute key
        ///</summary>
        VOLUME_MUTE = 0xAD,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Volume Down key
        ///</summary>
        VOLUME_DOWN = 0xAE,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Volume Up key
        ///</summary>
        VOLUME_UP = 0xAF,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Next Track key
        ///</summary>
        MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 0xB0,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Previous Track key
        ///</summary>
        MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 0xB1,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Stop Media key
        ///</summary>
        MEDIA_STOP = 0xB2,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Play/Pause Media key
        ///</summary>
        MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0xB3,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Start Mail key
        ///</summary>
        LAUNCH_MAIL = 0xB4,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Select Media key
        ///</summary>
        LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT = 0xB5,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Start Application 1 key
        ///</summary>
        LAUNCH_APP1 = 0xB6,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Start Application 2 key
        ///</summary>
        LAUNCH_APP2 = 0xB7,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
        ///</summary>
        OEM_1 = 0xBA,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the '+' key
        ///</summary>
        OEM_PLUS = 0xBB,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the ',' key
        ///</summary>
        OEM_COMMA = 0xBC,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the '-' key
        ///</summary>
        OEM_MINUS = 0xBD,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the '.' key
        ///</summary>
        OEM_PERIOD = 0xBE,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
        ///</summary>
        OEM_2 = 0xBF,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard. 
        ///</summary>
        OEM_3 = 0xC0,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard. 
        ///</summary>
        OEM_4 = 0xDB,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard. 
        ///</summary>
        OEM_5 = 0xDC,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard. 
        ///</summary>
        OEM_6 = 0xDD,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard. 
        ///</summary>
        OEM_7 = 0xDE,
        ///<summary>
        ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
        ///</summary>
        OEM_8 = 0xDF,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Either the angle bracket key or the backslash key on the RT 102-key keyboard
        ///</summary>
        OEM_102 = 0xE2,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 95/98/Me, Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000/XP: IME PROCESS key
        ///</summary>
        PROCESSKEY = 0xE5,
        ///<summary>
        ///Windows 2000/XP: Used to pass Unicode characters as if they were keystrokes.
        ///The VK_PACKET key is the low word of a 32-bit Virtual Key value used for non-keyboard input methods. For more information,
        ///see Remark in KEYBDINPUT, SendInput, WM_KEYDOWN, and WM_KEYUP
        ///</summary>
        PACKET = 0xE7,
        ///<summary>
        ///Attn key
        ///</summary>
        ATTN = 0xF6,
        ///<summary>
        ///CrSel key
        ///</summary>
        CRSEL = 0xF7,
        ///<summary>
        ///ExSel key
        ///</summary>
        EXSEL = 0xF8,
        ///<summary>
        ///Erase EOF key
        ///</summary>
        EREOF = 0xF9,
        ///<summary>
        ///Play key
        ///</summary>
        PLAY = 0xFA,
        ///<summary>
        ///Zoom key
        ///</summary>
        ZOOM = 0xFB,
        ///<summary>
        ///Reserved 
        ///</summary>
        NONAME = 0xFC,
        ///<summary>
        ///PA1 key
        ///</summary>
        PA1 = 0xFD,
        ///<summary>
        ///Clear key
        ///</summary>
        OEM_CLEAR = 0xFE
    }

    internal enum ScanCodeShort : short
    {
        LBUTTON = 0,
        RBUTTON = 0,
        CANCEL = 70,
        MBUTTON = 0,
        XBUTTON1 = 0,
        XBUTTON2 = 0,
        BACK = 14,
        TAB = 15,
        CLEAR = 76,
        RETURN = 28,
        SHIFT = 42,
        CONTROL = 29,
        MENU = 56,
        PAUSE = 0,
        CAPITAL = 58,
        KANA = 0,
        HANGUL = 0,
        JUNJA = 0,
        FINAL = 0,
        HANJA = 0,
        KANJI = 0,
        ESCAPE = 1,
        CONVERT = 0,
        NONCONVERT = 0,
        ACCEPT = 0,
        MODECHANGE = 0,
        SPACE = 57,
        PRIOR = 73,
        NEXT = 81,
        END = 79,
        HOME = 71,
        LEFT = 75,
        UP = 72,
        RIGHT = 77,
        DOWN = 80,
        SELECT = 0,
        PRINT = 0,
        EXECUTE = 0,
        SNAPSHOT = 84,
        INSERT = 82,
        DELETE = 83,
        HELP = 99,
        KEY_0 = 11,
        KEY_1 = 2,
        KEY_2 = 3,
        KEY_3 = 4,
        KEY_4 = 5,
        KEY_5 = 6,
        KEY_6 = 7,
        KEY_7 = 8,
        KEY_8 = 9,
        KEY_9 = 10,
        KEY_A = 30,
        KEY_B = 48,
        KEY_C = 46,
        KEY_D = 32,
        KEY_E = 18,
        KEY_F = 33,
        KEY_G = 34,
        KEY_H = 35,
        KEY_I = 23,
        KEY_J = 36,
        KEY_K = 37,
        KEY_L = 38,
        KEY_M = 50,
        KEY_N = 49,
        KEY_O = 24,
        KEY_P = 25,
        KEY_Q = 16,
        KEY_R = 19,
        KEY_S = 31,
        KEY_T = 20,
        KEY_U = 22,
        KEY_V = 47,
        KEY_W = 17,
        KEY_X = 45,
        KEY_Y = 21,
        KEY_Z = 44,
        LWIN = 91,
        RWIN = 92,
        APPS = 93,
        SLEEP = 95,
        NUMPAD0 = 82,
        NUMPAD1 = 79,
        NUMPAD2 = 80,
        NUMPAD3 = 81,
        NUMPAD4 = 75,
        NUMPAD5 = 76,
        NUMPAD6 = 77,
        NUMPAD7 = 71,
        NUMPAD8 = 72,
        NUMPAD9 = 73,
        MULTIPLY = 55,
        ADD = 78,
        SEPARATOR = 0,
        SUBTRACT = 74,
        DECIMAL = 83,
        DIVIDE = 53,
        F1 = 59,
        F2 = 60,
        F3 = 61,
        F4 = 62,
        F5 = 63,
        F6 = 64,
        F7 = 65,
        F8 = 66,
        F9 = 67,
        F10 = 68,
        F11 = 87,
        F12 = 88,
        F13 = 100,
        F14 = 101,
        F15 = 102,
        F16 = 103,
        F17 = 104,
        F18 = 105,
        F19 = 106,
        F20 = 107,
        F21 = 108,
        F22 = 109,
        F23 = 110,
        F24 = 118,
        NUMLOCK = 69,
        SCROLL = 70,
        LSHIFT = 42,
        RSHIFT = 54,
        LCONTROL = 29,
        RCONTROL = 29,
        LMENU = 56,
        RMENU = 56,
        BROWSER_BACK = 106,
        BROWSER_FORWARD = 105,
        BROWSER_REFRESH = 103,
        BROWSER_STOP = 104,
        BROWSER_SEARCH = 101,
        BROWSER_FAVORITES = 102,
        BROWSER_HOME = 50,
        VOLUME_MUTE = 32,
        VOLUME_DOWN = 46,
        VOLUME_UP = 48,
        MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 25,
        MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 16,
        MEDIA_STOP = 36,
        MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 34,
        LAUNCH_MAIL = 108,
        LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT = 109,
        LAUNCH_APP1 = 107,
        LAUNCH_APP2 = 33,
        OEM_1 = 39,
        OEM_PLUS = 13,
        OEM_COMMA = 51,
        OEM_MINUS = 12,
        OEM_PERIOD = 52,
        OEM_2 = 53,
        OEM_3 = 41,
        OEM_4 = 26,
        OEM_5 = 43,
        OEM_6 = 27,
        OEM_7 = 40,
        OEM_8 = 0,
        OEM_102 = 86,
        PROCESSKEY = 0,
        PACKET = 0,
        ATTN = 0,
        CRSEL = 0,
        EXSEL = 0,
        EREOF = 93,
        PLAY = 0,
        ZOOM = 98,
        NONAME = 0,
        PA1 = 0,
        OEM_CLEAR = 0,
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Define HARDWAREINPUT struct
    /// </summary>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        internal int uMsg;
        internal short wParamL;
        internal short wParamH;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to try this! It looks promising! Thank you for the very detailed response as well! Instead of just telling me what I need to do you actually helped me learn how to do it!

Comment: Awesome Work!! I have a quick question, how would you simulate key down and key up? THNAK YOU A LOT @Gareth

Comment: Look at the structs. You can use VirtualKeyShort.UP and VirtualKeyShort.DOWN

Comment: Does using other `KEYEVENTF` such as `KEYUP` and `KEYDOWN` (value 0) affect games registering these simulated inputs?

Comment: I like how you've condensed a lot of the different codes needed, but aren't a lot of them available via the `Keys` enum?

Comment: Do you know how can I put some delay between the keys?

Comment: @Gareth: I fixed it. I wanted to "press" a key and then to wait some time (1 second or something) before "pressing" another key. I used multiple SendInput calls and it worked. 

Great code, though! Thank you!

Comment: Great! Thanks. What about situation when you want for example print Capital Letter. So you need to hold shift and + letter. How to simulate that?

Comment: FYI, to avoid the massive virtual key/scan code enums, just use MapVirtualKeyA (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeya), that way you can use the Keys enum from the WinForms library (cast to a uint) and it will return the appropriate scan code.

Comment: This solution doesn't work with Tekken 7 videogame :)

Answer (score 6):

Adding on to the great answer from @gareth, to simulate capital letters during a sentance you can use my solution below..

```
public static void SendWithShift(ScanCodeShort a){
    HoldLShift();
    Send(a);
    ReleaseLShift();
}
public static void HoldLShift(){
    var Inputs = new InputStruct[1];
    var Input = new InputStruct();
    Input.type = 1; 
    Input.U.ki.wScan = ScanCodeShort.LSHIFT;
    Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KeyEventF.SCANCODE;
    Inputs[0] = Input;
    SendInput(1, Inputs, InputStruct.Size);
}
public static void ReleaseLShift(){
    var Inputs = new InputStruct[1];
    var Input = new InputStruct();
    Input.type = 1; 
    Input.U.ki.wScan = ScanCodeShort.LSHIFT;
    Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KeyEventF.KEYUP | KeyEventF.SCANCODE;
    Inputs[0] = Input;
    SendInput(1, Inputs, InputStruct.Size);
}
public static void Send(ScanCodeShort a){
    var Inputs = new InputStruct[1];
    var Input = new InputStruct();
    Input.type = 1;
    Input.U.ki.wScan = a;
    Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KeyEventF.SCANCODE;
    Inputs[0] = Input;
    SendInput(1, Inputs, InputStruct.Size);
}
```

To send shift and hold, you simply need to send but to release shift you need to ADD the keyup flag, not just set it.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for **emulation of multimedia button presses** and found that you need to use these parameters(in *@Gareth code*):

```
Input.U.ki.wVk = VirtualKeyShort.VOLUME_MUTE;
Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.UNICODE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @ogggre on `keybd_event`. I managed to have a working DllImport:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern void keybd_event(
    byte bVk,
    byte bScan,
    uint dwFlags,
    uint dwExtraInfo
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I just created a library to simulate keyboard and mouse (cursor) using dotnet core with multiplatform implementation.

Here is the link for github: https://github.com/lucassklp/Desktop.Robot

Comment: This lib doesn't work with Tekken 7 videogame :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SendKeys.Send("<your character/string>");`
Example:

`SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");`

Source: *https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-simulate-mouse-and-keyboard-events-in-code*

Comment: `SendKeys.Send(string)` has limited support in Windows 10, and isn't useful for all use cases.  If someone does use the contents of this answer, be advised that there's a non-zero chance that it could fail to work.

Answer (score 0):

`keybd_event` should do the job:

```
     // Simulate a key press
     keybd_event( VK_NUMLOCK,
                  0x45,
                  KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0,
                  0 );

     // Simulate a key release
     keybd_event( VK_NUMLOCK,
                  0x45,
                  KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,
                  0);
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you! I think this is exactly what I'm looking for! I'll be sure to test it ASAP and get back to you!

Comment: Actually I'm looking for something that'll work with C# and .NET. I'm sure this'll work if I were using C++, but is there anyway you can give me the C# reference for this? Thanks!

Comment: I just tried 
  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Gareth's solution since the keys get stuck after calling `Send()`.  Here is a simplified version of @Matthew Wherry's `ReleaseLShift()` so that it works with any key.

```
public static void ReleaseKey(ScanCodeShort key)
{
    var Inputs = new INPUT[1];
    var Input = new INPUT();
    Input.type = 1;
    Input.U.ki.wScan = key;
    Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.KEYUP | KEYEVENTF.SCANCODE;
    Inputs[0] = Input;
    SendInput(1, Inputs, INPUT.Size);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Windows Input Simulator makes this super easy.

The Windows Input Simulator provides a simple .NET (C#) interface to simulate Keyboard or Mouse input using the Win32 SendInput method. All of the Interop is done for you and there's a simple programming model for sending multiple keystrokes.
Nuget package -> Install-Package InputSimulator

https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

Comment: Posting [duplicate answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38108293/1677912) is frowned upon. These answers, in particular, seem more like ad copy than a programming answer, which also makes them seem spammy. If the answer can't be tailored for the specific question, a simple comment would be a better option.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help another user.  Your effort is appreciated.