# C# using Sendkey function to send a key to Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

I'm trying to send a key stroke to Windows operating system in a C# console application. 
I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292175/c-sharp-using-sendkey-function-to-send-a-key-to-another-application) that sends a keystroke to a an application like notepad.

How can I send the key stroke to the main windows process ?

Comment: _the main windows process_ meaning what??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# using Sendkey function to send a key to another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292175/c-sharp-using-sendkey-function-to-send-a-key-to-another-application)

Comment: @TaW I meant the Operating System Process that handles input/output

Comment: @Franck I refereed to this link in my question.

Comment: _the Operating System Process_ which would be what?? You can only send keys to an application that actually takes focus, ie has a UI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate keyboard input in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482338/simulate-keyboard-input-in-c-sharp)

Comment: "the Operating System Process that handles input/output".  That would be the kernel.  It's easy to send keys to the kernel.  Plug a keyboard in and press the keys.