# Anyone knows how to virtually click keyboard's keys with a UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm creating a sort of program that holds the letter W in games to avoid AFK penaltie

I tried reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection?view=winrt-22621) but is a complete mess.
Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: It might be useful to understand why you're trying to do this. Are you looking to simulate someone typing to a person looking at the screen? Are you trying to automate some testing?  

The documentation you linked looks like touch input, like a pen on a tablet or something, that doesn't sound like what you're looking for.  Perhaps post some code for what you've tried?

Comment: @Kevon im doing a sort of program that holds the letter W in games to avoid AFK penalties

Comment: did you see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482338/simulate-keyboard-input-in-c-sharp

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To inject keyboard input, you will need to create a **[InputInjector class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.inputinjector?view=winrt-22621)** first. It represents the virtual input device for sending the input data. Then you will need to create a **[InjectedInputKeyboardInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.injectedinputkeyboardinfo?view=winrt-22621)** which contains the key input. After that, you could call `inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput` method to inject the keyboard input.

Please also note that the APIs in the [Windows.UI.Input.Preview.Injection Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection?view=winrt-22621) require the `inputInjectionBrokered` restricted capability.

Here is the code that you could refer to:

```
InputInjector inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();

            var controlkey = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
            controlkey.VirtualKey = (ushort)(VirtualKey.LeftControl);
            controlkey.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None;

            var altkey = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
            altkey.VirtualKey = (ushort)(VirtualKey.Menu);
            altkey.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None;

            var delkey = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
            delkey.VirtualKey = (ushort)(VirtualKey.Delete);
            delkey.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None;

            inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { controlkey, altkey, delkey });

            controlkey.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp;
            altkey.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp;
            delkey.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp;

            inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { controlkey, altkey, delkey });
```