# SendInput can not properly simulate keyboard in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, sendinput

I am trying to simulate mouse and keyboard events by using `SendInput()` in C#. The mouse simulated perfectly, while the simulation for the keyboard is not working.

In that case, I tried to use another language to hook the keyboard to determine if it really works, but I could not hook anything. I tried to see if there are any errors, but `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` returns `0`, which means there is no error. I also tried to run as administrator, but it did not work.

After that, I found a [similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644881/simulating-keyboard-with-sendinput-api-in-directinput-applications) on StackOverflow, and I tried to change the code to `KeyEventFlags.KEYDOWN | KeyEventFlags.SCANCODE` and `KeyEventFlags.KEYDOWN | KeyEventFlags.UNICODE`, but they both did not work.

Here is the code:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize);
```

```cs
KEYBDINPUT keyboardInput = new KEYBDINPUT();
keyboardInput.dwFlags = (uint)(KeyEventFlags.KEYDOWN);
keyboardInput.wVk = (ushort)'A';
    
InputUnion union = new InputUnion();
union.ki = keyboardInput;

INPUT[] input = new INPUT[1];
input[0].type = (uint)InputTypes.KEYBOARD;
input[0].U = union;
Console.WriteLine(SendInput(1, input, Marshal.SizeOf(union)));
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
```

Note: I only press the key down, but it should still return `1` and have been hooked, while it returns `0` now.

Here is the code that defines enums:

```cs
public enum InputTypes : uint
{
    MOUSE = 0,
    KEYBOARD = 1,
    HARDWARE = 2
}

public enum MouseEventFlags : uint
{
    ABSOLUTE = 0x8000,
    LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,
    LEFTUP = 0x0004,
    MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,
    MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,
    MOVE = 0x0001,
    RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,
    RIGHTUP = 0x0010,
    WHEEL = 0x0800,
    XDOWN = 0x0080,
    XUP = 0x0100,
    HWHEEL = 0x01000
}

public enum KeyEventFlags : ushort
{
    KEYDOWN = 0x0000,
    EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001,
    KEYUP = 0x0002,
    UNICODE = 0x0004,
    SCANCODE = 0x0008
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct INPUT
{
    public uint type;
    public InputUnion U;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct InputUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public MOUSEINPUT mi;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public KEYBDINPUT ki;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MOUSEINPUT
{
    public int dx;
    public int dy;
    public uint mouseData;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct KEYBDINPUT
{
    public ushort wVk;
    public ushort wScan;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct HARDWAREINPUT
{
    public uint uMsg;
    public ushort wParamL;
    public ushort wParamH;
}
```

I wonder why this is not working, and which step I got wrong.

Comment: I think wScan needs to be set. See here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5264831/How-to-Send-Inputs-using-Csharp

Comment: One issue: SendInput should use SizeOf(INPUT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, you need to use `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` to release the key.

And I agree with Simon, `cbSize` is the size, in bytes, of an INPUT structure. You should need to use `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT))` instead of `Marshal.SizeOf(union)`.

You could refer to the links:

[Simulate keyboard input in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482338/simulate-keyboard-input-in-c-sharp)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput#example

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, I just want to use the code to demonstrate that it is not working. I tried to add it before I post this question, but it still did not work. Also, if that's true, how to press a key for 1000ms and then release?

Comment: @HanHan `SendInput` isn't optimized for cheating in computer games. Its purpose is to have the ability to implement input devices in software (such as on-screen keyboards).

Comment: @IInspectable Well, I don't really play muti player games and I do not like to do that, and I just want to make a remote control program that can help me manage my devices. By the way, is there anyone who has learned C# and still cheats in games? Shame...

Comment: @HanHan `SendInput` has no provision (or notion) for keeping a key pressed for a specific interval of time.

Comment: @IInspectable According to the document, `SendInput` is the new function for [`keybd_event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event?redirectedfrom=MSDN), and we can achieve that by calling the function and using `Thread.Sleep();`

Comment: Just tested, `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT))` can work and keep pressing one key, thanks for help!