# c# SendKeys.SendWait function, send numpad digits

Tags: c#, digit, numpad

so I was working on an application which supposed executes digit keys for another application which isn't made by me, this application only supports numpad digits and it doesn't support the digits below F1-12s so whenever I execute "{number}" or just "number" ex:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{1}");
```

or

```
SendKeys.SendWait("1");
```

just simple nothing happens, any one got idea on how to send number as numpad digit?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b5771d8-a34c-4c48-b8e3-72f200fd92b7/sendkeys-to-send-a-number-pad-key?forum=Vsexpressvb

Comment: this topic is with visual basic programming which got nothing to do with c# also I have browsed all these questions and topics none could help.

Comment: Then convert it to c#.  That's trivial.  It's just showing you how it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer on this topic

[How to simulate a Ctrl A + Ctrl C using keybd_event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395377/how-to-simulate-a-ctrl-a-ctrl-c-using-keybd-event)

here's the area to find keys:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx