# Change data template on key press and send key to template

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I have a custom control which is rendered as a cell in a data grid (Infragistics). All cells are displayed with its read-only template. The cells can be selected (provided by Infragistics).

Now if the user press for example "3" I change the template from read-only to an edit template. Which works fine.

The edit template contains a text box that should have the focus afterwards and also receive the keypress, eg. 3. The problem is that at the time I receive the keypress and change the template, it is not rendered yet of course.

**Control**

```
public class Cell
{
  //dependency properties
  public DataTemplate ReadOnlyTemplate;
  public DataTemplate EditTemplate;
  public DataTemplate CurrentTemplate;

  OnPreviewKeyDown()
  {
    CurrentTemplate = EditTemplate;
  }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Cell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Cell}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Content="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{Binding CurrentTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I cannot use `OnApplyTemplate` because the template is rendered directly within the cell but in one of the children.

Here are some ideas I came up with to solve

- collect the keypress events until the template is rendered and then focus the textbox in the edit template and push the keypress events to it
- "somehow" put the rendering in a priority dispatcher and wait "sometime" until it is rendered and then do the GUI actions

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried to use `DataTemplateSelector` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: E.g. set the `ContentTemplateSelector` property for cell and bind it to textbox text

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the following

```
cell.Dispatcher?.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => OnCellEnteredEditMode(cell)));

private static void OnCellEnteredEditMode(Cell cell)
{
  //traverse through the visual tree of the cell down to the first item which I can set to focus to
  //use win32 API to send key press
}
```

[How to simulate a Ctrl A + Ctrl C using keybd_event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395377/how-to-simulate-a-ctrl-a-ctrl-c-using-keybd-event)